# How can I use DFS and BFS to sort and rank data?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

For my group project, I need to implement an algorithm to sort through the data and then rank it. My data set is a wildfire data set that an using to solve two questions: rank the seasons from most to least based on how many wildfires have occurred and rank the states with the most fires in a given year.

A small screen shot from my data set:

[image]

Is there a way that I can add a counter to my BFS and DFS search in order to acquire the answers to my problem I am trying to solve?

Comment: Please don't link pictures; copy the data here instead, we have nice table formatting markup

Comment: Also, why BFS/DFS when you can have map for sorted data, boost::multi_index_container for data sorted on multiple indices?

Comment: This doesn't strike me as a tree problem where DFS or BFS would make sense. `vector` of structures and a couple different sorting predicates.

Comment: Unless your homework requirements specifically require C++, SQL probably makes quite a bit more sense. Even being generous and not having used SQL in 20 years or so, I'm still pretty sure writing SQL for both queries would take less than 10 minutes.

Comment: @user4581301 do you have a recommendation of a sorting algorithm that is not linear?

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I totally agree however I need to use a type of sorting algorithm

Comment: @Jess: `sort by [count] desc` uses a sorting algorithm. :-) But okay, assuming you're doing this in C++, you still almost certainly want a `struct` for each row, and a `vector<stuct>` for the full set. From there, since you mostly want counts, you'll probably have something like a `std::map<std::string, int>` to get a count of fires per state/fires per season. Then since you want a basically a histogram, you'll probably want to copy that to another vector to sort (usually using `std::sort`) by count before printing it out.

Comment: Throw all your records into a `std::vector`.  Create `std::map<key, vector_index>` tables for each field you want to use as a search key.  This is known as an *index table*, and a frequent concept used by databases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to do your homework for you, but here's a small program that does pretty much the same thing with some slightly different data to give at least some idea of an approach to this sort of job.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

struct Count {
    int value;
    std::size_t count;

    Count(std::pair<int, std::size_t> const &c) : value(c.first), count(c.second) {}

    bool operator<(Count const& other) { return count < other.count; }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Count const &c) {
        return os << c.value;
    }
};

struct rawData {
    std::string name;
    int height;
    int weight;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, rawData &r) {
        return is >> r.name >> r.height >> r.weight;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::map<int, std::size_t> heightCounts;
    std::map<int, std::size_t> weightCounts;

    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "usage: stats <filename>\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    std::vector<rawData> data { std::istream_iterator<rawData>(infile), {} };

    for (auto const &d : data) {
        ++heightCounts[d.height];
        ++weightCounts[d.weight];
    }

    std::vector<Count> heights { heightCounts.begin(), heightCounts.end() };
    std::vector<Count> weights { weightCounts.begin(), weightCounts.end() };

    std::sort(heights.begin(), heights.end());
    std::sort(weights.begin(), weights.end());

    std::cout << "Most common weights:\n";
    std::copy(weights.rbegin(), weights.rbegin() + 2,
             std::ostream_iterator<Count>(std::cout, "\n"));

    std::cout << "\n\nmost common heights:\n";
    std::copy(heights.rbegin(), heights.rbegin() + 2,
              std::ostream_iterator<Count>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

This processes a data file something like this:

```
Tom 70 225
Joe 67  190
Jim 75 225
Bill 70 215
```

If you run it with that as the input data, the result should look like this:

```
Most common weights:
225
215


most common heights:
70
75
```